# getting 500 error when accessing magento using custom host file

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a production instance of Magento 1.9 (`www.example.com`), and I have a test instance that is running on `1.1.1.1` server.

In windows, I have edited my host file on my computer like below:

```
1.1.1.1 example.com
```

I am now getting HTTP ERROR 500 when I try to browse the test instance by going to `example.com`

Comment: Your test instance on 1.1.1.1 is probably not configured to answer requests for www.example.com domain. Even if you hit the correct ip, server needs to know which directory to serve, by using the hostname. Also Magento instance needs to be configured to use that domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the test instance in `1.1.1.1` is running without errors and make sure that the Base Url (Secure and Non Secure) in test server is configured correctly based on the accessing domain.

Also, If you configured Magento web domains with `www`, you should add both www and non-www in your hosts file, like below:

```
1.1.1.1 example.com
1.1.1.1 www.example.com
```

Hope that helps.